# Does not display set value in TextView in Android Fragment

Tags: android, textview

I am an Android programming beginner. Appears my problem is simple and silly, still not able to locate the issue.

In the fragment, my objective is to show a dot every second which helps prompting someone to do some physical action, but no way near that. I am moving bit by bit and got struct at the first level itself.

```
public class ActionFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentActionBinding binding;
    TextView pCycleNum;
    int pCycle;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action, container, false);
        pCycleNum = v.findViewById(R.id.pCN);
        pCycleNum.setText(String.valueOf(1));

        binding = FragmentActionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(ActionFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_ActionFragment_to_LauncherFragment);
            }
        });

        binding.buttonAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            pCycleNum.setText("5");
            }

        });
    }
```

I am setting pCycleNum to 5. But when I run the app on emmulator, it does not show any change. Not able to find out where I am going wrong.

The fragment xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:foregroundTint="@color/teal_700"
    tools:context=".ActionFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:backgroundTint="#F57F17"
        android:text="@string/goback"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_second"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="178dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="139dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.13"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.97" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pCN"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@color/teal_200"
        android:textSize="96sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView13"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please help to me to locate the error why app not displaying the set value. Also help me to understand why it is doing so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you got a textview by id from `v` layout but then inflated a new layout, gave its reference to binding and returned the binding view not the view you used findViewById on

to avoid this mistake afterwards, just get your views from the binding object, you'll find them all by their id names (without any underscore character "_") like I did in `binding.pCN`

```
public class ActionFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentActionBinding binding;
    TextView pCycleNum;
    int pCycle;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        binding = FragmentActionBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        pCycleNum =binding.pCN;
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(ActionFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_ActionFragment_to_LauncherFragment);
            }
        });

        binding.buttonAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            pCycleNum.setText("5");
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Omar. It worked well. I tried your suggestion too apart from Vaibhav's. Thanks for explaining and also helping so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these lines from onCreateView() method.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action, container, false);
    pCycleNum = v.findViewById(R.id.pCN);
    pCycleNum.setText(String.valueOf(1));
```

And then use `binding.pCN.setText("5");`

This happened because you are using both findViewById() and view binding simulataneously.
And you are returning the binding in onCreateView() method. And onViewCreated() method don't know from where to get this pCN text view so it just skips.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav. It worked well and understood the issue behind this non-working code. And thanks again for quickly answering.